# jQuery on PHP echo

Tags: jquery, doctrine

Need help with this one. I'm kind of confuse.
For me everything seems fine but I'm still getting error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$'
```

Here's my code

```
echo "$('.gro-ls').click(function(){$(this).css({background:'red'})});";
```

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with this one?

Thanks

Edited: All the answers worked. Thanks guys

Comment: if you use " " php tries to parse variables so he thinks $(this) is an php variable, while ( is not allowed in variable names [exactly as the error messages states, so just use ' ' instead

Comment: PHP parses `"` (double quotes). Try escaping the `"` or use `'` (single quotes) instead

Comment: Any particular reason that you have the JavaScript being printed using PHP? Could you not temporarily close the PHP tags when printing out lines that do not require PHP?

Comment: I've tried all of the fixes you gave me

changing from `"` to `'`

and the

`echo "\$('.gro-ls').click(function(){\$(this).css({background:'red'})});";`

It all worked thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

PHP [parses/expands variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) in [double quoted strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double), and $something is a variable.

Try this:

```
echo "\$('.gro-ls').click(function(){\$(this).css({background:'red'})});";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `"` to `'`

It should look like this:

```
echo '$(\'.gro-ls\').click(function(){$(this).css({background:\'red\'})});';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes.

```
echo '$(".gro-ls").click(function(){$(this).css({background:"red"})});';
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the double quotation marks, it's looking at the dollar sign and thinking it is a PHP variable. If you switch the double quotation marks with single quotation marks and vice-versa, it should work.

Like this: `echo '$(".gro-ls").click(function(){$(this).css({background:"red"})});';`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$jq = <<<JQU
$('.gro-ls').click(function(){
    $(this).css({background:'red'});
});
JQU;
echo $jq;
```